# Integrating PayPal with console application

Tags: c#, sockets, console, paypal

I am programming a server, which needs to receive payment information from paypal (PayPal), in C#, but it isn't supposed to be via website (I've found many "walkthroughs" for that), it is supposed to receive the payment information via console, or any other non-graphical way. 
Is it possible? If it is, how can I do it? Can I do it via sockets?
I've heard about wcf, but I don't know if it will help me achieve my objectives. 
If you could please tell me where to look I'll be very grateful. 
Thanks in advance and sorry for any english mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can do it from a C# GUI, you can do it from a console program.  You need the [PayPal C# SDK](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks).

Comment: The problem is that I can't reference System.Web.UI and System.Web.UI.WebControls in console applications. The biggest problem here is that I'm a newbie. I've been programming in C# for only 2 weeks. I have been able to do some very simple socket applications, GUI programs, and a few simple websites handling MySQL databases, but I don't even know where to start with this problem.

Comment: Why can't you use a web app instead?

Comment: Orders. The boss doesn't want it, so I need to manage somehow, but if it's impossible I can, MAYBE, convince my boss.

Comment: First off, you can reference System.Web in console applications.  Read this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033194/system-web-ui-not-available-in-console-app.

Comment: Second off,  I don't see why you guys wants a console applications.  GUI's rule for a reason.  I would build either an internal facing WebApp or a Desktop Program using like WinForms or something.  At least then you take advantage of modern software features.  I know you have to do what you can with that you have but if I had a boss that made me build a console application,,,, I wouldn't have a boss that made me build a console application. lol.

Comment: I agree with you, but that isn't the reality in my conutry. Sometmies you have to work with servers that were bought during the last century and you have to manage. Somehow I've been able to pull off some very impressive improvised technical resource (a pretty word for making something work on a computer that is a piece of garbage (I would say s**t, but I don't know if swearing is allowed)). And another thing, I can call System.Web, I just can't call System.Web.UI and System.Web.UI.WebControls.

Comment: Mand, if you know how to do it, could you please say: go read this article, etc. At this point I will even take insults as a help. The good thing is that I've got a few months to make everything work. If you want I could tell you what I need to do. But I don't know if it will help.

Comment: I understand. I meant to convey that last comment in joking tone. :) I really think you should be able to call System.Web.UI from a console program, make sure it is added a reference.  Also, welcome to stackoverflow.  I suggest creating a full account and accepting answers to all questions, it will help for future questions.

Comment: If it's possible to add friends in stackoverflow consider yourself added. You've been extremely helpful and so is everyone here. I will check everything about stackoverflow later when I'm at home. I think that at the speed I'm advancing in C# maybe I'll be able to help you someday, but at the moment it's impossible. Do you accept kidneys as payment? Mine are destroyed because of the alcohol, but maybe you can sell them later. lol

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) to make arbitrary http requests.  Granted, this will be much more difficult than using the aforementioned SDK.  You will be building requests and parsing responses; most of which the SDK is doing for you.