# why can't I add a reference to system.web

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to add a reference to System.Web to my VB.net 4.0 Console application Project so I can use the [HTML encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) function. I don't see System.Web in the add reference box.

[image]

This code shows namespace cannot be found

```
Imports System.Web.HTTPUtility
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What's your project type, and which framework version are you targeting?

Comment: @JonSkeet how can i determine my project type?

Comment: Go into your project properties. I don't know what tab it's in for VB projects. Something like "Class library", "Windows Forms application" etc.

Comment: @akh2103, what John means is that; what type of project is it ... asp.net web site OR winform OR WPF OR ...

Comment: @akh2103: What edits? You haven't edited your question.

Comment: @akh2103, why do you need a reference to "system.web" in a Console application?

Comment: @Rahul going to be using the console application to transmit data to a third party using http post

Comment: Have a look into this post: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3033194/system-web-ui-not-available-in-console-app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033194/system-web-ui-not-available-in-console-app) This post describes the same issue and gives solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the .NET 4 Client Profile. Change it to the full framework under the Project settings.

For C#, look under the "Application" tab for the "Target Framework" option.

For VB .NET, look under the "Compile" tab for the "Advanced Compile Options" button. Click that, and the last option will be for the target framework.

Comment: I right clicked project-->properties. Where do I go from there?>

Comment: Thanks. I am using visual studio 2010 professional. I am in the application tab. Where do go to find the "Target Framework" option.

Comment: It is under compile-->advanced compile options-->target framework

Comment: Yup, I just realized you're using VB, not C#. That's my bad. I'll update my answer with VB information in a moment.